# como crear un bat para comprobar la existencia de un directorio y entra para ejecutar un programa

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

Intento crear un iso de windows 10 en la cual se instale office 2019 y la única forma que se puede hacer es con los siguientes comandos (la iso de windows tengo varios programa que se instalan junto a windows, pero office no me resulta sin el ejemplo de abajo)

```
E:
cd E:\sources$OEM$$$\Setup\Files\Office
SETUP /CONFIGURE OFFICEPROX64.XML
```

El directorio contiene dos archivos (setup.exe y el .XML)

Pero la letra de la unidad cambiara según el equipo y los disco duros que tenga, entonces quería saber como puedo hacer para que compruebe la ubicación y ejecute lo demás

Comment: Como dice la respuesta de abajo usando: "cd" se comprueva si la ruta existe o no. Si existe te dirije a ese lugar y si no te lanza un error.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el batch en tu unidad, lo normal es que vallas directamente a los directorios de la misma:

```
cd sources$OEM$$$\Setup\Files\Office
SETUP /CONFIGURE OFFICEPROX64.XML
```